# How to pass spinning bar to another component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am in a scenario where I have to add a spinning bar in the component say,

List.js

```
class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       //spinning bar should be displayed here

      </div>
    );
  }}
```

But the spinning bar should be displayed when another method in Actions(i.e redux) is called. So How will I pass this from actions.js to the render component in List.js

Actions.js

```
export const getList = (listInfo) => dispatch => {
 //Spinning should start here
  return application.getClientInfo(userInfo).then(
    listInfo => {
//spinning should stop here
          return dispatch(getListInfo(listInfo))
    },
    error => {
      return dispatch(apologize('Error in getting application'))
    }

  )

}
```

getList and ListComponent is called in main.js

main.js

```
render() {
         this.props.getClientApplication(this.props.user);

      return (
            <div>
                   <List />
            </div>

      );
    }
```

So how will I add render method here that is actually to be displayed in list.js? Please help

Comment: You might want to look at [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your reducer, keep a loading state and dispatch an action to set and clear loading states as and when you want

```
class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 }
  render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
       //spinning bar should be displayed here
       {isLoading  &&  <Spinner>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Actions.js

```
export const spinner = isLoading => {
  return {
    type: actionType.SPINNER, isLoading
  }
}
export const getList = (listInfo) => dispatch => {
 //dispatch loading action
  dispatch(spinner(true));
  return application.getClientInfo(userInfo).then(
    listInfo => {
          dispatch(spinner(false))
          return dispatch(getListInfo(listInfo))
    },
    error => {
      dispatch(spinner(false))
      return dispatch(apologize('Error in getting application'))
    }

  )

}
```

Also make sure you aren't dispatching an action in render without using suspense

```
render() {
         this.props.getClientApplication(this.props.user);

      return (
            <div>
                   <List isLoading={this.props.isLoading} />
            </div>

      );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this, but type is not changing from LOADING to LOADING COMPLETED.

Comment: I gave a separate function like, export const spinner = isLoading => {
  return {
    type: actionType.SPINNER, isLoading
  }
} and then in getList, dispatch(spinner('Loading'))

Comment: shouldn't you be passing true or false `dispatch(spinner(true))`

Comment: yes I have passed true or false.For more clarity I used the term Loading. But the value doesn't change to false

Comment: did you dispatch an action to set isLoading to false aft3er the promise resolved. also you need to handle it in the reducer as well

Comment: Yes. I have set it to false. In reducer I gave ,  case actionTypes.SPINNER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { isLoading: action.isLoading });

Comment: So now where is the value not changing to false. what is the value of isLoading in the List component

Comment: Like you mentioned in the answer, I gave  listInfo => {
          dispatch(spinner(false))
          return dispatch(getListInfo(listInfo))
    },
    error => {
      dispatch(spinner(false))
      return dispatch(apologize('Error in getting application'))
    } and value of isLoading in List component is _true_

Comment: value changes to false in this, export const spinner = isLoading => {  console.log("Spinner value"+isLoading)
  return {
    type: actionType.SPINNER, isLoading
  }
} But on taking it using this.props.isLoading in List.ijs it i always false.

Comment: If you can create a codesandbox demo or something, I can have a look. Its pretty difficult to determine what exactly is going wrong in your case with the above code